# Using Composer scripts defined in composer.json, how to display phpunit colors?

Tags: php, phpunit, composer-php

## Context

I'm using Composer scripts defined in my `composer.json` file to run unit tests in my application.

**My `composer.json`:**

```
{
    "name": "my company/my_application",
    "description": "Description of my application",
    "license": "my licence",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.6",
        "ext-soap": "*",
        "ext-ssh2": "*",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ext-zip": "*",
        "ext-pdo_mysql": "*",
        "ext-gettext": "*",
        "dusank/knapsack": "^9.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "ext-mysqli": "*",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^5.7",
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "2.*"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test-php": "vendor/bin/phpunit --colors --verbose --bootstrap tests/bootstrap.php --configuration tests/phpunit.xml",
    }
}
```

**My command is:**

```
vendor/bin/phpunit --colors --verbose --bootstrap tests/bootstrap.php --configuration tests/phpunit.xml tests/
```

## Problem

If I run `vendor/bin/phpunit --colors --verbose --bootstrap tests/bootstrap.php --configuration tests/phpunit.xml tests/` inside a terminal, I can see colored output. But if I run it using Composer, I don't see any color.

## Question

Using Composer scripts defined in composer.json, how to display phpunit colors?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To force phpunit to display colors in any situations, add `=always` to the `--color` parameters.

With

```
vendor/bin/phpunit --colors=always --verbose --bootstrap tests/bootstrap.php --configuration tests/phpunit.xml tests/
```

in my `composer.json` file, I can see colors.